# What is stands for "New User"?

Tags: discussion, new-users

What is the criteria or parameter for a user to change from New User.

Number of **days** or **Reputation**.If so how many days or how much reputation?

Note: I'm not asking about privileges or Restrictions of new user.

My reference is [this](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=newusers)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user, also: http://askubuntu.com/help/search?q=new+user

Comment: @muru thank you, but I'm not asking about privileges and restrictions...  I'm asking with respect to [this](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=newusers)

Comment: So what prevented you from saying that in the question in the first place?

Comment: @muru "what prevented"? nothing! .

Comment: down voter please comment!

Comment: You do realise the downvoter doesn't get notified, but as the only commenter here, I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you head to the last page (irrespective of the sorting applied), it's reasonably obvious it refers to users created in the last 45 days.

Comment: Seems to be rather 46 days: https://askubuntu.com/users?page=392&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate - and you only see that sorted by **creation date**.

Comment: @ByteCommander rounding off + update delays, I'd say. 45 days + whatever time during the day the script runs ~ 46 days.

Comment: Sounds also possible...

Comment: @ByteCommander actually no, sorted by reputation, you'd see that that top user is the OP, so rep doesn't seem to be a limit, and the there are plenty of 1 rep users at 46 days.

Comment: Yesh... You see that rep is not taken into account. But it's hard to see an account age limit unless you read every user's info.

Comment: @ByteCommander "2125 in 36 days" hardness is relative.

Comment: +1 @muru for considering my hardness! ;=)

Comment: "*But it's hard to see an **account age limit** unless you read every user's info.*" (when sorted by reputation)

Comment: @Ravan: Don't forget to press the ☑ here on meta neither!  **:P**